# How to make `git log` show colors correctly in MobaXterm?

Tags: terminal, git, colors, window, mobaxterm

I tried `git config --global color.ui auto`, but it made no difference—the `git log` output is still full of `[[32m`, `[[m`, etc.

How can I make `git log` (and any other commands with color output) show up colors correctly in MobaXterm?

Comment: Git automatically launches the "less" pager for you I assume. If you type "git log | cat", do the colors show properly? If so, you'll need to pass "less" the "-R" flag e.g. via the environment variable $LESS.

Comment: `git log | cat` doesn't show colors at all.  (It doesn't even try to--no escape characters.)  Setting `LESS='less -R'` and running `git log` again results in the same escape characters showing up.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `git log | cat` combined with `color.ui always`.

Comment: That works.  But `less -R` throws an error.  It appears to be busybox less...any way to get that to show colors?  (If you don't know I'll ask as a new question.)

Comment: I don't know if busybox's less supports such option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by installing GNU less:

```
apt-get install less
```

This didn't work by itself — I'm not quite sure how aliases work in MobaXterm; they seem to be some sort of symlink, actually.  (Or maybe that's just for busybox aliases.)  Anyway, I had to copy the `less` executable which was installed in `/usr/bin/less.exe` to `/bin/less` so it would be the default `less` to be executed.  Then all was well.

---

UPDATE: On my new Windows computer, with MobaXterm 10.7, I didn't have to muck about with aliases to get `less` to work interactively.

However, I *did* have to add `unset GIT_PAGER` to my `~/.bash_profile` before Git would use the proper new `less`, since it was pointing directly to the busybox executable.  Before that, git colors worked correctly but it dumped a bunch of extra lines to my screen each time it opened `less`.

The command `less` itself is and was aliased to `_bbf less`, which is a clever little function that runs `/bin/less.exe` if it exists, if not runs `/bin/less` if it exists, and if not runs `/bin/busybox.exe` with its first argument set to `less`.  (This can be viewed with `type _bbf` but it's not really necessary.)

---

Here are my `~/.bash_profile` lines on MobaXterm that make everything work (in combination with having run `apt-get install less`):

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
export GIT_PAGER='/bin/less.exe -FRXSe'
```

Comment: By the way, this made it work for `git`, but not interactively—to do that I had to also `unalias less` so I would get `less` from the `PATH` variable instead of from my busybox alias.